# encrypting file that stores SQL passwords

Tags: apache, security, encryption

What is the most secure way to store usernames/password combinations for databases that are used by apache?

there must be something more secure than just storing cleartext passwords in a single file and putting them in a folder that only root and apache have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let me ask this: who are you protecting from? You want to be "more secure", but you haven't identified any attack vector.

1. External users

   If you're trying to protect them from external users, you have two options:

   1. Move the file outside of the webroot. Therefore, the attacker cannot get the file as Apache won't serve it.
   2. Protect the file via permissions or DENY in Apache. That way Apache won't serve it.

   The first option is better, as a misconfiguration can't expose the credentials.
2. Internal users (people who have access to the server)

   You can't protect against them. If the attacker can get on the server, they can (in general at least) get access to the credentials.

   Yes, you can encrypt the file. But Apache must know how to decrypt it, so the attacker can figure that out.

   Your only defense is to set permissions on the file properly. Make it so that it can only be read by Apache (nobody).

In short, there's little to no gain to encrypting credentials, as if your server is properly configured there's no chance of them leaking to someone that they wouldn't leak to already.

Protect your application from other attack vectors (SQLi, Code Injection, XSS, etc) as they are more likely to be the ways that an attacker is going to get in...

Comment: I have been thinking about creating a file that storing that info in environmental variables, and adding it to httpd.conf. Or Storing encrypted file outside of webroot, and giving apache a key that it can use to decrypt it, that was a user will need both, the key and the file in order to do anything with it. But after thinking about it and reading your response it even more obvious to me that if someone gains access to user apache there isn't much that I can do about it.